# Where does Django store sessions?

Tags: python, django, session, cookies, django-sessions

I have this code in my project that assigns a unique id to an anomymous user and saves it in a session:

```py
user_id = str(uuid.uuid4())[:5]
request.session['nonuserid'] = user_id
```

[Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#configuring-the-session-engine) says that sessions are stored in my database. I thought it would save it in `django_session` table. However, everytime a unique is created and saved in session(above code), no row is added to that table.

Then I checked cookies in `Resources`. There is no key with name `nonusedid`. Just some `sessionid`

So, where does it store the session data I created?

Relevant part of **Settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Default Django middleware.
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

DJANGO_APPS = (
    # Default Django apps:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cached_db'
```

Comment: Can You show us settings.py?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I thought it would save it in django_session table. However, everytime
>   a unique is created and saved in session(above code), no row is added
>   to that table.

Hopefully a new row is not added each time you add a key/value to the current session. Session's data are stored in serialized form (in the `django_session.session_data` field), and a new row is added only when a *new* session is started - all subsequent writes to the session will only update the `session_data` field's content.

Answer (score 0):

> If you want to use a database-backed session, you need to add 'django.contrib.sessions' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting.
>
> Once you have configured your installation, run manage.py migrate to install the single database table that stores session data.
> [as specified here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions)

Answer (score 0):

The only needs to use sessions in django as mentioned by you and other users are:

1- Add `SessionMiddleware` to **MiddlewareClasses**(You already have it):

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    # Default Django middleware.
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

2- Add `django.contrib.sessions` to installed apps (You already have it):

```
DJANGO_APPS = (
    # Default Django apps:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)
```

3- Sync the database after changing the Middleware and the DjangoApps:

```
    python manage.py syncdb
```

Now that you have done all of this the sessions has to be working, because there is no more beyond that. After you do all this changes try to surf for your website logging with different users or without user and you should be some information growing up in the `django_session` table

You should check the documentation about sessions at [Django using sessions in views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views)

Comment: @JohnyStark sorry for my previous comment, Are you using latest Django version ? 1.8 ? In this version **migrate** substitutes **syncdb**

Comment: You should try to do **syncdb** or **makemigrations** and then **migrate**

Comment: Yes I am using 1.8! Everything is in place. I noticed that when I login, then a row is added to the table. However, when I am logged out and create session myself like `request.session['someId'] = value` it is not saved. Maybe it is just the way it is? session data for anonymous users are not saved in database, just in cookies?

Comment: Check this link [When sessions are saved](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#when-sessions-are-saved). It seems you may want set the variable `SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST` to True

Answer (score 0):

The doc says below in [Technical details](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/http/sessions/#technical-details):

> - Session data is stored in a database table named `django_session`

And, the default session id `sessionid` is stored as a cookie in a browser as shown below:

[image]

In addition, with [SESSION_COOKIE_NAME](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name), you can change the default session id `sessionid` to other names like `hello` in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "settings.py"

SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = 'hello'
```

[image]