# Django: request.session is stable even when using multiple server?

Tags: django, session

According to some `Django` books and online codes, some values are passed as session variable when needing to redirect(in server side) with some context variables, e.g. `request.session['fruit'] = 'apple'`.

But I wonder it really works well even when I user multiple servers.(Let's call each server as A,B,C)

In this case, user's request can be **RANDOMLY** sent to one of these servers.
For example, first request is sent to A server and next request is sent to B server and third request go to A server again.

So, I just thought that session data (`request.session`) could be lost or going messy because of this randomness.

Am I right? or Since session is a server-side data based on **user's cookie session-id** and saved in database, so I don't have to worry about it?

Thanks :)

Comment: related on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345962/11790764

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on which session backend you are using. Databases are usually centralized, so it doesn't matter which server handles the request if you're using the database backend.

Caches may be local to the server. You need to take this into account if you want to use the cache or cached db backend. The cached db backend uses a write-through cache: the data is only retrieved from the database if the cache is empty or when new data is written. Other servers might have stale data in their local cache if you change the session.

So if you are using the cache or cached db backend, you need to have a centralized cache store where the sessions can be saved.

Comment: I'm using `'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware'`, which means that I don't have to worry about session gonna mess up?

Comment: @user3595632 You need the middleware regardless of the session backend you're using. What matters is your [`SESSION_ENGINE`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#session-engine) setting, but this defaults to using the database backend. So if you haven't changed the default (and you're using a centralized database), you don't have anything to worry about.